# Unable to send Attachment in Webchat using directline, same code is working fine in emulator

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, direct-line-botframework

```
var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
{
     Name = @"application.png",
     ContentType = "image/png",
     ContentUrl =  "base64sting"
});

await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(response);
```

Above code throwing the below exception in webchat when i try to send attachment to user , in emulator it is working fine

> at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String
>   conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2
>   customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\Conversations.cs:line 1121
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations
>   operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity
>   activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\ConversationsExtensions.cs:line
>   241
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line
>   316
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.d.MoveNext()
>   in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\TurnContext.cs:line 267

I even tried this

```
using (var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl)))
{
    var attachments = new Attachments(connector);
    var response = await attachments.Client.Conversations.UploadAttachmentAsync(
        conversationId,
        new AttachmentData
        {
            Name = @"Resources\architecture-resize.png",
            OriginalBase64 = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath),
            Type = "image/png",
        }
    );

    var attachmentUri = attachments.GetAttachmentUri(response.Id);

    return new Attachment
    {
        Name = @"Resources\architecture-resize.png",
        ContentType = "image/png",
        ContentUrl = attachmentUri,
    };
}
```

this is failing as well, is there any work around to send attachment to user using webchat without having hosted content url?

Comment: The name / details of the exception is missing in your details, you just added the path

Comment: Are you trying to send the image file to be displayed or as an item to click, save, download?

Comment: @StevenKanberg I was trying to send image as an item to click and save, i think i figured out the issue, directline supports only 4MB message size, the base64string of my image is very large , causing the message to exceed 4MB, now am uploading the image to azure blob and using the blob uri as contentURI , it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are facing this issue , below is the root cause.

I was trying to send image as an item to click and save, i think i figured out the issue, directline supports only 4MB message size, the base64string of my image is very large , causing the message to exceed 4MB, now am uploading the image to azure blob and using the blob uri as contentURI , it is working now